# Getting the .Text value from a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, textbox

I have a bunch of textboxes on my asp.net page, and on TextChanged event, I want to run a stored proc to return a **Name**, based on user input. If I have a block of code like:

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
string objTextBox = t.ID;
```

how can I get the `.Text` value of objTextBox?

Comment: You need a break and a coffee. ;-)

Comment: You have the textbox object, so just call .Text...

Comment: I was trying objTextBox.Text, but that wasnt working.

Comment: This is why giving your variables meaningful names is a good thing to do.

Comment: how is my variable naming not meaningful?

Comment: @Konrad, I need "good" coffee.

Comment: `objTextBox` suggests that the variable is of type `TextBox`. Using `strTextBoxId` or simply `textBoxId` would be less confusing as it clearly communicates that the contents of the variable is an ID and not a `TextBox` object. I would also recommend against the use of single letter variable names (the only exception being index variables) because they are hard to search for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this instead:

`string objTextBox = t.Text;`

The object `t` is the `TextBox`.  The object you call `objTextBox` is assigned the `ID` property of the `TextBox`.

So better code would be:

```
TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
string theText = objTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: I need .ID to check if the user input was on txtApproverID (the populate Approver name with stored proc result), if user enterd Manager ID, then enter Manager name, if DirectorID etc.

Comment: Duh. Thanks @K. I need intravenous coffee

Answer (score 8):

```
if(sender is TextBox) {
 var text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using `t.Text`?