# I have one table with three fields (username, usercode and logdetail) i want to insert Logged user Data into it but getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

here is my code...
output is..

asd 24  23
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:16:10 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:16:35 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:19:45 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:20:55 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:21:48 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:21:57 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:23:40 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:31:51 PM
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox   08/14/2018 4:35:23 PM

```
Session["User_name"] = "lbl_User";
    Session["Product_Code"] = "txt_PrdCode";


    myConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Product_Detail] ([User_name],[Product_Code],[Log_Detail]) values ('" + lbl_User + "', '" + txt_PrdCode + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "' ) ", myConn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the .Text value from a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334388/getting-the-text-value-from-a-textbox)

Comment: 2 main issue here. First a TextBox is a web control with a lot of properties. If you wan't to access the Text value of the TextBox you should use the Text property.

Comment: Then please stop hand crafting  your sql query. Use either [parametrise query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement) or an orm.

Comment: What do you expect with this, line 1 : `Session["User_name"] = "lbl_User";` Because here your Session Username is "lbl_User" not the value of the label...

Comment: lbl_user stores User_Name and txt_PrdCode stores Product_Code

Comment: here i want to stored Logged user Details ie. his Name Which Product code he search and Exact time with date in database

Comment: Label have a `InnerText` property. And TextBox a `Text` property. It should be enought to get the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

if you take the values from `code behind`
you have to write thig like this

```
Session["User_name"] = lbl_User.Text;
Session["Product_Code"] = txt_PrdCode.Text;
```

but first, you have to make this controls `runat="server"`

this will solve your problem