# C# use textbox as filename for streamwriter

Tags: c#

This is my first time using `StreamWriter` and so far I've only figured out how to make it save using a specified filename. Is it possible to use what's in a TextBox field as the filename when saving? In this I want to use `Fname.Text` for the filename.

**what I have so far:**

```
void Save_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
        sw.WriteLine(Fname.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(Lname.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, grab the text from the texbox field into a variable, then where you have the "test.txt" replace it with the string variable from the textbox.

Comment: "test.txt" is text.  A String.  It is not a control reference

Comment: Question is unclear to me, could you please describe what you want to achieve. is your **Fname** is text box name? does it contains file name. Where do you want to write the data

Comment: If you're using WinForms you should use [`SaveFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.1) to get file names from the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the .Text value from a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334388/getting-the-text-value-from-a-textbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use it as the parameter in your `FileStream` constructor like so:

```
  void Save_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream(Fname.Text + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
            sw.WriteLine(Fname.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(Lname.Text);
```

Comment: I tried Fname + ".txt" kinda feel stupid for not just adding .Text thanks!